# Define or Cast variable type dynamically in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this func:

```
Future<void> syncedData(String dataType, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  // Open the Hive Box
  await _openBoxByName(dataType);

  // Put each data element in the Hive Box
  data.forEach((k, v) {
    Workout _v = v;
    // var _v = v as Workout; - kinda same result

    _putData(k, _v.toJson().toString(), dataType);
  });
}
```

I also have 3 Model Classes: `Workout`, `Days` and `Years`.

In order for me to get `.toJson()` method from v, I need to do: `Workout _v = v;`.
But I do not know how can I cast the type of `v` dynamically from `Workout`, `Days` and `Years` Model Classes?

If I do not cast `v` explicit as Workout Class Model, dart doesn`t know about any of my WOrkouts methods.

I have tried something like this, but it did not work:

```
if  (dataType == 'workout')  Workout _v = v;
if  (dataType == 'days')  Days _v = v;
if  (dataType == 'years')  Years _v = v;
```

Thank you

Comment: Why not use `dynamic _v` in this case?  You have a dynamic type (i.e., the type is known only at runtime), so using `dynamic` is appropriate.

Comment: if I dont implicitly or explicitly tell dart that v is a type of Workout, I cannot call my methods

Comment: wait, it worked ...

Comment: A `dynamic` type is not type-checked.  You can still call your methods as long as they exist on the object.

Comment: I was mislead by IDE, that it did not found the methods :(.

Comment: It's not possible for the IDE to find methods on a `dynamic` object since its type won't be known until runtime.

Comment: thank you James, I leave and "re-learn".

Answer (score 0):

You should probably encode this as a Map that has values for keys of workout, days, or years.  I think that'll JSON quite nicely.

Comment: they already are using json_serialized inside each Class Model, therefore: toJson() method